# dropOperator done on Matrix of a Matrix - How is this done?

Tags: matrix

I have implemented this dropOperator from [dropOperator from stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299798/efficient-way-to-pick-delete-a-list-of-rows-columns-in-a-matrix-in-mathematica) and works fine on a single Matrix. But now I have a Matrix of a Matrix and want to drop some rows or columns (in the pic below f.e row 2,5,7) of Matrixes of that Matrix-Matrix. It seems that this could not be done with that dropOperator described in the above link.

Can anyone help please? Thanks!

This should work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you need special functions to do what you want instead of using `Drop`. I think you should provide a minimum working example of your starting "matrix of matrix" and what you want the end result to be.

In any case try this:

```
m = Array[FromDigits[{##}] &, {3, 3, 4}]

Drop[m, {2}] // MatrixForm

Drop[m, None, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

**Edit**

Okay after I posted I've just read your revised Q.

Here is a starting point that seems to be a similar form to yours:

```
m = Array[FromDigits[{##}] &, {9, 4, 6, 2}];
MatrixForm[m]
```

[image]

So to drop rows 2, 5, and 7:

```
Part[m, {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
unevenDropRow[m_, pos_] := Part[m, Complement[Range[Length[m]], pos]]
unevenDropCol[m_, pos_] := Part[m, All, Complement[Range[Length[m[[1]]]], pos]]
```

Note that the above are specific for the problem you have raised. They may need to be expanded/generalised depending on how typical this is of your usage. You can combine the row and column drops into one:

```
unevenDrop[m_, rowpos_, colpos_] := Part[m, Complement[Range[Length[m]], rowpos], 
  Complement[Range[Length[m[[1]]]], colpos]]

unevenDrop[m, {2, 5, 7}, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, that was it I was looking for!